# How to reverse a substring of a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to reverse a substring in a string. For example

```
string x = "foobar";
```

So I want to reverse `foo` to be `oof` so x would be `"oofbar";`
Here's a sample of what I have tried:

```
string x = "foobar";
size_t pos = x.find("foo");
reverse(x.begin() + k, s.end()); // I got stuck here.
```

Comment: This is a nice easy exercise. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you try something? Weren't not here to do you work for you.

Comment: There's a standard algorithm for that: [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: Please post what you have tried and explain where you are running to problems.

Comment: People who give it an honest attempt usually add their code, and ask where it fails. They don't write with a demanding tone either, i.e. "I want such and such".

Comment: in place or out of place?

Answer (score 8):

For a simple case as

```
string x = "foobar";
```

you can use

```
std::reverse(x.begin(), x.begin() + 3);  // reverse the first three letters.
```

---

If `"foo"` is embedded in the string, i.e. it is not at the start of the string, you'll have to find its location first.

```
string x = "whoknowswhereitisfoobar";
auto loc = x.find("foo");
if ( loc != std::string::npos )
{
   std::reverse(x.begin() + loc, x.begin() + loc + 3);
}
```

---

If you don't want to hard code the number 3, you can use `std::string::size()`:

```
string hay = "whoknowswhereitisfoobar";
string needle = "foo";
auto loc = hay.find(needle);
if ( loc != std::string::npos )
{
   std::reverse(hay.begin() + loc, hay.begin() + loc + needle.size());
}
```

[<kbd>**See Live Here**</kbd>](https://www.ideone.com/il8nOU)

Comment: loc != hay.end() gives me error.

Comment: @DoeHarris do this: `if ( loc != std::string::npos )`

Comment: @DoeHarris, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Given `auto x = "foobar"s` and `const auto value = "foo"s`, I'd probably use iterators just cause of their convenience:

```
const auto it = search(cbegin(x), cend(x), cbegin(value), cend(value));

if(it != cend(x)) {
    x.replace(it, next(it, size(value)), crbegin(value), crend(value));
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/xHvcFN)

Comment: @Bob__ Note that in both algorithms I use iterators to `x` and iterators to `value` so no, there is no overlap